# Can not launch Cadence

Tags: cadence

I am trying to start Cadence on my linux computer with Centos release 6.7. The problem I am having is after I type in icfb & on the terminal I am getting the below error which couldn't let me launch Cadence.

```
 *WARNING* voInit failed to find the passwd entry for (null), using '/tmp' for a home directory.
The most likely cause of this problem is the failure of NIS lookups.
Please contact your system administrator.
*WARNING* clsInit failed: Success
*WARNING* file /home/john/CDS.log Success
*WARNING* file /home/john/CDS.log.1 Success
*WARNING* file /home/john/CDS.log.2 Success
*WARNING* file /home/john/CDS.log.3 Success
*WARNING* file /home/john/CDS.log.4 Success
*WARNING* file /home/john/CDS.log.5 Success
*WARNING* file /home/john/CDS.log.6 Success
*WARNING* file /home/john/CDS.log.7 Success
*WARNING* file /home/john/CDS.log.8 Success
*WARNING* file /home/john/CDS.log.9 Success
Failed to lock log file: /home/john/CDS.log.9
```

I will be very great full if anyone here can help me how to solve it.

Sincerely,

Answer (score 0):

Here's an article I found on sourcelink that seems to cover your error:

The problem is related to the fact that winbind is being used as name service. Here is how the  /etc/nsswitch.conf file is configured:

passwd:     files winbind
shadow:     files winbind
group:      files winbind

This also explains why the problem does not exist for local users. The solution is to go to the Winbind Authentication Configuration and  then in the Options tab turn on the following two flags:

Cache User Information
Use Shadow Passwords

If systems are configured to use LDAP (i.e. passwd files ldap in nsswitch.conf) for user information and Kerberos for user authentication. We also need to verify certain shared object libraries are installed on the system. Most often it is solved by installing the 32 bit nss_libraries i.e. package nss_ldap.i386 - (64 bit version was already installed) for RHEL. This installs the /usr/lib/libnss_ldap.so required for the LDAP authentication.

The new RHEL6 way of authenticating is not the libnss, but a newer tool SSSD. If the host use sssd to handle user authentication, the 32 bit version of libnss_sss.so should also be installed. It has been observed that the above errors could also come if the service calls "nscd" is not running for sssd.

LINUX%   sudo yum install sssd-client.i686 nss-pam-ldapd.i686